# Changing data type from date to date/time in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using mysql Db. I having a field like current_date in date data type. I have thousands of data right now.

Now I want to capture the time of the current_date field. So now I am going to change the data type from date to date/time.

Is this cause any problem to do this?
Suppose I changed, what about the old records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old records will just recieve a time value of 00:00:00

At least, this is what occured for me when converting date to datetime via phpmyadmin

Therefore the result should be 2010/11/11 00:00:00

Comment: so, i think there is no problem..... what u think?                     Thanks for ur reply

Comment: I think there will be no problem, though if you have a large amount of data perhaps do a backup first, or run a test on another test database. Always better to be safe :)